# spring mvc touch file and serve it as resource

Tags: spring, file, model-view-controller, resources, touch

How can I create a file and serve it as a resource, my */src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/web/dispatcherServlet-context.xml* file snippet:

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Any nice approaches?